# JProfiler connection issue: no profiling agent is listening on a remote host on the port prepared by jpenable

Tags: jprofiler

I'm new to JProfiler and don't understand this error. The port is provided by jpenable:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the remote session is not connecting to the machine where you ran jpenable on. Did you try the attach feature without jpenable? On the "Quick attach" tab of the start center you can make a remote connection and select a JVM there.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for answer. I can use remote debugger in my IntellJ. I can also use VisualVM to connect the same remote JVMs (but using JMX port instead of those suggested by jpenable)

Comment: I see, but the SSH tunnel that is configured in JProfiler might go somewhere else. Try using the bin/jpcontroller utilty on the remote side to check if that can attach to the JVM on the port prepared by jpenable.